# django rest framework "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'router'"

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-rest-viewsets

i have imported   all the restframework packages but i don't understand why am i getting this strange error

```
from django.conf.urls import *
from django.contrib import admin
from django.views.generic.base import TemplateView
from .views import Create,Home,signup,Search,QuestionViewSet
from django.urls import reverse
from .models import Question
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from rest_framework import  routers
router=routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(prefix='question1',viewset=QuestionViewSet)
app_name='main'

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^/',views.home,name='home'),
    url(r'^home/',Home,name='home'),
    url(r'^ques/',Create.as_view(success_url="/index/home/"),name='ques'),
    url(r'^signup/',signup,name='signup'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout,name='logout'),
    url(r'^search/',Search,name='search'),
    url(r'^api/', include('router.urls'))


    # CreateView.as_view(model=myModel, success_url=reverse('success-url'))

]
```

this is the issue i'm facing

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'router'
```

any kind of help is appreciated 
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

First argument of `include` method can be module name or pattern list. Since `router.urls` is patterns list it should be

```
url(r'^api/', include(router.urls))
```

instead of

```
url(r'^api/', include('router.urls'))
```

So you need to remove `''` signs.